# Can I add additional tags to a file to be used for searching

Tags: windows, file, filesystems, tags, keyword

Products like Picasa build databases that include metadata about files.  Captions, keywords locations and the like.

Files have a number of attributes that is dependant on the file type and / or the application that produced the file.

My question is can I programmatically add a tag to a file and then use this tag to search for content.

Eg. Text files include Name, Type, Folder Path, Size, Date Created, Date Modified, Attributes, Owner, Computer.  How can I add a "Keywords" attribute?

I am interested in a solution in C# but am primarily asking for help in understanding how this functionality could be implemented in Windows operating systems.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Extended Attributes, but they don't have a good API in Windows and in general are not widely used. There also exist Alternate Data Streams, but these are ,as the name suggests, *data* streams, and not attributes.